# CSS gradient text not showing when animating in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a gradient text which I am trying to animate with animate.css. The animation takes place but the text is not showing, it's transparent. If I remove the animation classes it looks the way it should look. 
How can I fix it ?

Note: It works fine on Chrome and Edge. Only in Firefox I came across this problem.

Works when color is not transparent ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enrcdpxv/10/)):

```js
$(".text").css("animation-delay", "1s").addClass("animated lightSpeedIn");
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css);

div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="text">Hello World</span></div>
```

Doesn't work when color is transparent ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enrcdpxv/11/)):

```js
$(".text").css("animation-delay", "1s").addClass("animated lightSpeedIn");
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css);

div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="text">Hello World</span></div>
```

Comment: I want to the text to be gradient in color and also animate it at the same time. This works in Chrome perfectly. I am trying to figure out to to achieve this in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a glitch in firefox. It can't do both the animation and the clipping on the same element. Move the animation to the container (the `div`):

```js
$(".container").css("animation-delay", "1s").addClass("animated lightSpeedIn");
```

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><span class="text">Hello World</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in CSS

```
background: #2F7336;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #AA3A38, #2F7336);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #AA3A38, #2F7336); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
```

this work in all browser

Comment: Old browser is not an issue for me. It doesn't work in the latest version of Firefox. That's the only issue I have. and even If you use background as a solid color and clip the background to text, then the result is even worse. You just see a solid colored block, no text is viable unless you double click on the element. See here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enrcdpxv/12/)